# R programme.How to get column name for particular string, for given different columns for different strings? I have written this:

Tags: r

How to get column name for particular string, for given different columns for different strings? I have written this:

```
 x = read.csv(file.choose())
 a = nrow(x)
 b = ncol(x)
 c = 0
 cr = function(y) { 
for(i in 1:b) 
 {  for(j in 1:a)
   {      if(!is.null(x[i,j]) && x[i,j] == "y")
           {       c[i] = c[i]+1           }
    } 
 }
 return(c)  
}
cr("Fashion")
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, give an example please. Does this work? `colnames(iris)[colSums(iris == 'setosa') > 0]`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
cr = function(y) colSums(x==y)
```

That gives you the number of occurrences of `y` in each column of `x`.